# Finding Text Color in AutoCAD VBA from an Exploded Block

Tags: vba, excel, autocad

In AutoCAD I have several blocks that each consist of a circle with a number inside. I exploded each block and now am trying to get the color of the text into an excel file but when I do explodObj(a).Color or bloomcol I only get the color of the circle and not the text color? Any help would be great!

```
    Dim textobj As Variant
    Dim bloomcol As Variant
    Dim textcol As Variant
    For a = 0 To UBound(explodObj)
        'Returns the text string
        textobj = explodObj(a).TextString
        Sheet1.Cells(i, 1) = textobj

        'Doesn't return anything
        textcol = textobj.Color
        Sheet1.Cells(i, 6) = textcol

        'Returns color of circle not text
        bloomcol = explodObj(a).Color
        Sheet1.Cells(i, 7) = bloomcol

    Next
    textobj = 0
```

Comment: I just tested your code and it worked just fine for me (except had to remove the "doesn't return anything" section as it just errors because strings don't have color.

Comment: For some of them it works fine but others it return the outside circle color or the fill in the circle. Maybe it has something to do with the color not being one of the 256 to choose from in AutoCAD - I'm not sure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put in an if statement and it seems to be working now

```
    Dim textobj As Variant
    For a = 0 To UBound(explodObj)
        textobj = explodObj(a).TextString
        Sheet1.Cells(i, 1) = textobj

        If TypeOf explodObj(a) Is AcadText Then
            Sheet1.Cells(i, 7) = explodObj(a).Color
        End If

    Next
    textobj = 0
```